# ImageButton disappears on screen orientation change

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity, android-fragments, android-button

I am developing an android app and I am fairly new to the android environment. I am using google map, and drop a pin. When the user selects the pin a button that is originally hidden appears and can be pressed to delete the pin on the map. However when the screen is rotated (and the pin remains selected) the delete button disappears. How do I keep this button visible even after a screen rotation? Note: the button should only be visible when the user has selected a pin on the map.

Here is the code I use to set up up the marker click listener:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        currentMarker = marker;

        deleteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);
        deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                marker.remove();
                deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
});
```

I also override the `onPause()` method so I can call save the MapFragment's state like so:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

All of this code works fine except when I rotate the device and the button disappears even while the marker remains selected. What is the best way to keep this button visible?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is not displaying is because the `Activity` is getting recreated after you rotate the device; the whole `View` hierarchy will be recreated.

Also, you are calling `mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true)` too late on the lifecycle. Try calling `setRetainInstance()` in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`. Ideally, you would call `setRetainInstance()` inside the `Fragment`.